# Contact intent insert City,Country,ZipCode

Tags: android, android-intent

I am Inserting contact using following code.

```
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT); 
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE); 
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY,ConstantData.mainTable.getCompany_name());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL,ConstantData.mainTable.getAddress1()+" "+ConstantData.mainTable.getAddress2()+" "+ConstantData.mainTable.getAddress3()+",City: America"); 
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,ConstantData.mainTable.getTelephone_number());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE,ConstantData.mainTable.getMobile_number()); 
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL,ConstantData.mainTable.getEmail_address()); 

    startActivity(intent);
```

But I am not able to insert City,Zip-code and Country,So How to insert it using Intent??

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? Or how about browsing the source of the gingerbread sourcecode to find where they are storing addresses? Come on exhaust your options, don't expect an answer from such a short sighted approach.

Answer (score 0):

I added a contact but not using Intent. Here is the code:

```
void addingContact(String firstName, String phoneMobile, String street, String poBox, String city, String state, String zipCode, String country)
{
  ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                                    .build());

                        //---------------------- Names
                            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, firstName)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName).build());

                        //--------------------- Mobile Number
                            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneMobile)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                                    .build());


//--------------------------------- address   
                               ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET, street)
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, city)
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION, state)
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, country)
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE, 
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
                                        .build());

try 
                            {
                                context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                            } 
                            catch (Exception e) 
                            {               
                                e.printStackTrace();
//                               Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
}
```